# Using cardano-node installed by Daedalus as CLI?

Tags: daedalus, cardano-node

I want to do some transaction with custom metadata and was wondering if I have to install another instance of `cardano-node` or if it's possible to use the already installed version by Daedalus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

First, you need to install `cardano-cli` binary (you can find it in the Hydra build system, depending on your OS which might be [Linux](https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-node-linux/latest-finished), [Windows](https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-node-win64/latest-finished) or [Mac OS](https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-node-macos/latest-finished).

After you have your `cardano-cli` installed, you now need to set your `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` environmental variable to the location of your `cardano-node` socket file that is being run by Daedalus.

This code snippet will do just that, extract the path to the socket file from the `cardano-wallet` instance.

Depending on the network, you will execute the following for **testnet**:

```
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=$(ps ax | grep -v grep | grep cardano-wallet | grep testnet | sed -r 's/(.*)node-socket //')

# Check var it must be path for file of node socket and not empty
echo $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH
```

Or the following for **mainnet**:

```
# Create var CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=$(ps ax | grep -v grep | grep cardano-wallet | grep mainnet | sed -r 's/(.*)node-socket //')

# Check var it must be path for file of node socket and not empty
echo $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH
```

After you have done that, you can now try to query the network using your `cardano-cli`, for **testnet**:

```
$ cardano-cli get-tip --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

Or for **mainnet**:

```
$ cardano-cli get-tip --mainnet
```

Source: [this useful gist](https://gist.github.com/ilyar/09eda2bb01545296aa9e1351b8218086)

Comment: Could you expand some more on how to use this? It's not immediately clear to me from just looking at the Gist.

Comment: @ValentinWalter can you check now? I tried to elaborate it a little bit more.

Comment: I found on Mac OS that the sed -r option doesn't work, but using -E does.